# How to insert the entered numbers into the diagonal

Tags: python

As usual, was practicing python and got this exercise:

Create a 4 * 4 matrix with values of 1,2,3,4 on the main diagonal of the
array.

Input and output legend:

```
Enter your value: 4
[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 2. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 3. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. 4.]]
```

Did this so far, not much yeah but can't get how to approach to this task

```
import numpy as ar
x = ar.zeros((4, 4))
x[::2, 1::2] = 0
x[1::2, ::2] = 0
print(x)
```

Comment: `np.diag`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `np.fill_diagonal()` [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html)

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((4, 4))
np.fill_diagonal(x, [1,2,3,4])
print(x)
```

Output:

> [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
> [0. 2. 0. 0.]
> [0. 0. 3. 0.]
> [0. 0. 0. 4.]]

---

**Automatically using the number from your input:**

```py
import numpy as np
input_val = int(input('Enter your value:'))
x = np.zeros((input_val, input_val))
np.fill_diagonal(x, range(1,input_val+1))
print(x)
```

Output:

[image]